# Keyword based searches from multiple data files

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to identify data entries based on keywords search. This approach was successful when I searched the keywords separately for each file. Here is my code

```
SELECT distinct ON (file1.id) file1.id, file1.notes1

FROM  file1

where file1.notes1 similar to '%((significant)|(important))%';
```

I was hoping the same approach would work for multiple files. but my queries are taking longer. Is there a more efficient way to approach queries from multiple files ?

PS I have a large list of keywords but I am posting only 2 keywords in this example code.

```
SELECT distinct ON (file1.id) file1.id,file2.date,file2.time, file1.notes1, 
file2.notes2

FROM  file1, file2

where file1.id= file2.id
AND (file1.notes1 similar to '%((significant)|(important))%' OR file2.notes2 
similar to '%((significant)|(important))%');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to rewrite it with `UNION ALL/UNION`:

```
SELECT file1.id, file1.notes1
FROM  file1
where file1.notes1 similar to '%((significant)|(important))%'
UNION 
SELECT file2.id, file2.notes1
FROM  file2
where file2.notes1 similar to '%((significant)|(important))%';
```